# Two novels about a company that runs online puzzle competition with real world consequences?

Tags: story-identification, books

A woman runs these puzzle games. I think the first game is in Indonesia, the second maybe in Turkey. In the second one the game gets mixed in with politics to a slightly dangerous degree.

Comment: What's science fiction or fantasy in these books?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots An online puzzle game that warps reality so that the real world is affected seems pretty SFF-ish to me. On the other hand, this question is a bit broad.

Comment: @gallifreyan: I'm under the impression from the body that it's more "the CIA thinks it's really a terrorist plan" than "The superspy from the game has come into existence from collective belief."

Comment: Even if this is not Off Topic, it is certainly Too Broad until we see more detail.

Comment: You're right about the possible lack of SFF, I may be conflating it with other similarly themed stories. Just been frustrating not to be able to track this down online.

Comment: We do have a Literature SE, but they're kind of bearish on story ID questions.

Comment: For what it's worth - this is almost certainly Walter Jon Williams' This Is Not A Game. It's set in the near future, so it's borderline SF, I guess...

Comment: @andrewsi The reference to Indonesia certainly does match that.

Comment: The science fiction elements of "This is Not a Game" include an AI investment program that is crashing currency values worldwide, creating chaos, and the concept of crowd-sourcing alternate-reality gamers for real-world purposes (which for the time the book was published was a SFish concept).